# Javascript to check ul ID and change a variable accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am creating a simple function that allows hovers based on sprites.  I don't want to repeat this code based on every possible car type (compact, convertible, suv, etc).  Instead I want an if statement that checks if the ul has a certain ID and if so changes the variable to one of said car types.  This variable will be placed in an img url.  Here is the javascript code I Have so far.

```
var img;
                        if (document.getElementById("car")) {
                            var img = "compact";
                        }
                        function rad_glowOn() {
                            document.getElementById("radiator").style.backgroundImage = "url(/af-demo/images/TW/"+img+"-carparts-glow.png)";
                            document.getElementById("healthAlert").style.display = "block";
                        }
```

Here is the HTML that it is referencing.  The UL's ID will be changing based on the car.  Haven't setup that yet.

```
<ul id="car">
                        <li id="carLinks">
                            <div id="healthAlert">
                                <p class="healthPopup-Header">Radiator</p>
                                <p>Radiator Leaking.  Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" id="radLink" onmouseover="javascript:rad_glowOn();" onmouseout="javascript:rad_glowOff();">                                 
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" id="engLink" onmouseover="javascript:eng_glowOn();" onmouseout="javascript:eng_glowOff();">
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" id="batLink" onmouseover="javascript:bat_glowOn();" onmouseout="javascript:bat_glowOff();">
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" id="frontWheel" onmouseover="javascript:mec_glowOn();" onmouseout="javascript:mec_glowOff();">
                            </a> 
                            <a href="#" id="backWheel" onmouseover="javascript:mec_glowOn();" onmouseout="javascript:mec_glowOff();">
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" id="passSeat" onmouseover="javascript:mec_glowOn();" onmouseout="javascript:mec_glowOff();">
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" id="driverSeat" onmouseover="javascript:mec_glowOn();" onmouseout="javascript:mec_glowOff();">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="radiator">                                        
                        </li>
                        <li id="engine">                                        
                        </li>
                        <li id="battery">                                        
                        </li>
                        <li id="mechanical">    
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

The car types are not actual ID's or classes.  I have a list of images and the variable is the first section of the image which is reflected in:

```
style.backgroundImage = "url(/af-demo/images/TW/"+img+"-carparts-glow.png)";
```

Right now I have to specify that image tag directly aka:

```
.style.backgroundImage = "url('/af-demo/images/TW/compact-carparts.png')"
```

My goal is to have a simple if statement that checks the ul's ID and assigns a value to the img variable that will be reflected to the above.

Comment: Please edit this into a better formed question. Also, `compact`, `convertible`, and `suv` are examples of classes, not IDs, as they are not necessarily unique, judging by the context of what you are doing.

Comment: I have edited my post a bit more.  Hopefully this adds clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
function rad_glowOn() {
    var thing = this.id.split('Link')[0];
    ...
}
```